# Scroll div from anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

I have div `.mdl-layout__content` which is `overflow-y: scroll`. What I want to achieve is, to scroll this div from anywhere inside body when I swipe touchpad or scroll mouse wheel.

Here is what I've done with [jquery mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)

```
    var $target = $('.mdl-layout__content');
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $target.scrollTop($target.scrollTop() - (delta * 5));
    });
```

The problem is related to this part `(delta * 5)`. It's speed is different when I use mouse wheel and swipe vertical with touchpad of laptop.

`(delta * 5)` - good speed for touchpad but awfully slow for mouse wheel

`(delta * 40)` - good speed for mouse wheel but awfully fast for touchpad

Is there anyway to detect if device is mouse or touchpad and set delta multiplier value based on this?

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this issue?

Comment: check this url work for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333061/jquery-mousewheel-doesnt-support-trackpad

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I don't quite understand how to implement correct answer on this link to my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332722/jquery-mouse-wheel-horizontal-scrolling-with-trackpad

Comment: @LaljiTadhani has nothing to do with my question